# не видит установленный коннектор JDBC

Tags: eclipse, webbrowser, mysqlconnector

при загрузке вебпроекта из браузера в элкипсе в консоли выбрасывает следующие сообщения об ошибке:

```
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NewWebProject20' did not find a matching property.
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 18 2017 20:54:42 UTC
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.75.0
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         F:\софт\JAVA\Workspace коды файлы программ для работы Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=F:\софт\JAVA\Workspace коды файлы программ для работы Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=F:\софт\JAVA\Workspace коды файлы программ для работы Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcSoft\Bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 683 ms
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
мар 21, 2017 2:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
мар 21, 2017 2:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
мар 21, 2017 2:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
мар 21, 2017 2:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 541 ms
0
мар 21, 2017 5:42:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet by.gsu.epamlab.servlets.PieceServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at by.gsu.epamlab.DAO.ConnectorDB.getConnection(ConnectorDB.java:26)
    at by.gsu.epamlab.DAO.AbstractDAO.<init>(AbstractDAO.java:20)
    at by.gsu.epamlab.DAO.PieceDAO.<init>(PieceDAO.java:28)
    at by.gsu.epamlab.servlets.PieceServlet.init(PieceServlet.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

А когда запускаешь эту же базу данных через раннер все работает прекрасно

Ошибка явно кроется здесь:

```
EVERE: Allocate exception for servlet by.gsu.epamlab.servlets.PieceServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Но не могу найти по форумам решения. Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу из-за этого доделать проект

Comment: Каким образом добавляете коннектор .jar  в проект?

Comment: через libraries

Comment: Properties - Java buildpath - add external Jar's

Comment: Ок, а как сам проект собираете, с помощью `maven` или `gradle`?  .jar находится в папке с проектом или нет? Ошибка явно говорит, что неправильно подключена библиотека. Нужно больше данных, чтоб воспроизвести ошибку.

Comment: разобрался нужно в самом проекте. Нужно найти вот такой путь :папка ваших проектов\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps. В этой папке уже есть ваш проект и здесь в папку lib нужно скапировать все сторонние библиотеки и тогда все работает нормально. Всю причину почему так делать я не знаю это подсказанный РАБОЧИЙ совет. Может кто-то объяснить по подробней и на пальцах почему так надо?

Comment: Почитайте что такое `CLASSPATH` при запуске в java, все станет на свои места. По сути это запуск проекта вместе с другими используемыми компонентами (с .jar файлом в данном случае), с указанием где эти компоненты можно найти. Если они требуются в проекте, а их нет, то возникает ошибка `ClassNotFoundException`. Вам посоветовали вручную добавить .jar файл в то место, откуда будет запускатся приложение, и где они будут искатся виртуальной машиной java при запуске (случай для эклипса). Лучший вариант использовать сборщик проекта, который добавит зависимые файлы в сборку.